# Handling Inputs where some columns MAY NOT exist

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm relatively new to building ETL's and I've been tasked with updating an old one that inserts directly into the DB table, and running it through the API instead.

The API payload only has 2 required fields out of 10-12 total.  What I would like to do is provide users with the ability to build a file that ONLY requires the 2 required fields as well as ONLY the fields they want to UPDATE.

Example: (R)=Required
Fields defined: `ID(R), Name, UPC(R), Description, X, Y, Z, A, B, C`
Actual input: `ID, Name, UPC, A`
`1234, Toy1, 555555, "StringForFieldA"`

I'm pretty positive I can handle everything once I read the file in... in the past, using the 'CSV File Import' step, if a field is defined and the columns do not exist in that order, the transformation fails. I would love it if my users could give me just the data they need rather than a file that is 90% empty because they are updating 2 fields.

Is there a step or series of steps that would allow me to do this? I looked at the ETL Metadata Injection but that looks like it wants to inject and map data from a database which I don't need.

Comment: Use metadata injection.before injecting filter the fields which are required using filter rows step,hence during every run it will take care of the mandatory fields among them will only be injected.

Comment: Its not so much about filtering fields out of the file.  The 2 required fields will always be there, but then the user has the option to include any/all of the rest of the fields.  I need the read from csv step to recognize what is there, and be ok with some fields not always being there... without blowing up and failing.

Comment: Metadata injection does the same-thing. Take the data from csv file step. Define the file-location, in fields define generalise name like Field1,Field2  upto 10 or 20 depends on the maximum limit you are expecting. so user sends 2 fields or 20, your transformation will handle it rather then failing.